# Recursive case class to DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How do you make a `DataFrame` given a `case class` that references itself? Take the following:

```
case class TestCase(id: Long, parent: Option[TestCase])
```

If I do:

```
val testCases = Seq(TestCase(1L, None), TestCase(2L, Some(TestCase(1L, None)))).toDF
```

It throws a big, 'olde `ScalaReflection` error. Of course, I could do:

```
case class TestCase(id: Long, parentId: Option[Long])
```

But that's not what I want.

Incidentally, `Avro` has no issue encoding and decoding recursive schemas. I don't think I'm asking the impossible. This seems like a very normal use-case for handling parent-child relationships.

**Update**

I can manually create a schema, but as far as I can tell, I have to hard-code how far up the chain you can go by repeatedly nesting the `StructType`s. Like this:

```
val schema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("id", LongType, false),
  StructField("parent", StructType(Array(
    StructField("id", LongType, false),
    StructField("parent", StructType(Array(
      StructField("id", LongType, false),
      StructField("parent", NullType)
    )))
  )))
))
```

Note that for the last `parent` up the chain, it's type is `NullType`. With the above schema, the following all work:

```
df.select($"parent")
df.select($"parent.parent")
df.select($"parent.parent.parent")
```

Based on the schema above, the first two might return `null`, or the parent. The third one always returns `null`.

Interestingly enough, to create the `Row` objects for the dataframe, I only have to do:

```
val testCaseSeq = Seq[TestCase](...)
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  sc.parallelize(testCaseSeq.map(tc => Row(tc.id, tc.parent))),
  schema
)
```

I guess this more or less works. I just have to figure out in advance how many levels of parent-child hierarchy to support. Which kind of sucks. But can anyone do better than this?

Comment: Spark SQL requires complete schema to be known when `DataFrame` is created so recursive definition simply cannot work. If relationship is linear you could encode it using simple collection types otherwise `GraphFrames` could be a better fit.

Comment: Any chance you want to give an example of one or both of those two? I have not worked with `GraphFrames` yet, but a huge part of my algorithms are done in `GraphX` already, so that might be the way to go.

Comment: Now that I think about it you are spot on -- the way to do it is change it from parent-child to node-edge-node.

Comment: I thought for a moment about collection it probably won't give you exactly what you want but schema would be like this (` TestCase(id: Long, ancestors: Seq[Long])`). Regarding `GraphFrames` there is no magic there. If you already familiar with GraphX it is the same idea.

Comment: Omg you can use something other than a `Long` as the Vertex ID!